# How to store properties of GridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

I have two forms in C#. One has a GridView and gets data from a database. The other controls of the color of cells of this GridView. When the application is closed, the color of the gridview should be reset to the original color without the lates changes. How could the latest changes of the GridView color persist if the application is closed and be set again when the application is startet again? I think this could be done by saving the state in a file, but how?

Comment: Please format your post as it's very tough to read in it's current form, add an example of your code to show us what you've tried and where it's falling over and we might actually have a chance to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You should save your setting/Properties in XML file on HD. and Read the file when application restarts.

Writing File
 XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();

```
            //  Root Node
            XmlNode RootNode = this.xDoc.CreateElement("DataGridView");
            xDoc.AppendChild(RootNode);

            //  AutoSize
            XmlNode AutoSize= this.xDoc.CreateElement("AutoSize");
            VisitID.InnerText = true;
            RootNode.AppendChild(AutoSize);

           //  PropertyTWoToSave
            XmlNode PropertyTWoToSave= this.xDoc.CreateElement("PropertyTWoToSave");
            VisitID.InnerText = 500;
            RootNode.AppendChild(PropertyTWoToSave);

            if (!Directory.Exists(this.FilePath))
                Directory.CreateDirectory(this.FilePath);           

          StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(this.FilePath + "\\" +                 this.FileName + ".xml");

        try
        {


            this.xDoc.Save(sw);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            sw.Flush();

            sw.Dispose();
        }
```

//--------------- Now Reading File

```
                if (File.Exists(this.FilePath + "\\" + this.FileName + ".xml"))
                {

                    DataSet dsTriage = new DataSet();

                    dsTriage.ReadXml(this.FilePath + "\\" + this.FileName + ".xml");

                    dgv.AutoSave=Convert.ToBoolean( dsTriage.Tables[0].Rows[0]["AutoSave"].ToString() );

               }
```